# Firebase Retrieval of Parent Value

Tags: java, firebase, parent-child

I want to retrieve the users id in firebase using the users phonenumber.In my scenario when a user clicks on one of these list of numbers the user must be able identify the uid for the selected user. Is there a possiblity of retracing the parent using a child key

```
"simplelogin:17" : {
      "name" : "pro",
      "number" : "1234"
    },
    "simplelogin:18" : {
      "name" : "Safar",
      "number" : "1234"
    },
    "simplelogin:19" : {
      "name" : "gp",
      "number" : "345465"
    },
    "simplelogin:20" : {
      "name" : "jose",
      "number" : "346"
    },
    "simplelogin:21" : {
      "name" : "jem",
      "number" : "12344"
    },
```

I have tried the following methods...however the result seems to be null

```
System.out.println("methodddd"+ getKeyFromValue(users,"number=12344,name=jem"));
System.out.println("getkeymethodddd"+ getKeysByValue(users,"number=12344,name=jem"));

public static <T, E> Set<T> getKeysByValue(Map<T, E> map, E value) {
    Set<T> keys = new HashSet<T>();
    for (Map.Entry<T, E> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (value.equals(entry.getValue())) {
            keys.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return keys;
}

public static Object getKeyFromValue(Map hm, Object value) {
    for (Object o : hm.keySet()) {
        if (hm.get(o).equals(value)) {
            return o;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I would restructure your database and I would create index by phone number containing user's IDs. It's fast and very effective.

Comment: Yes that is a effective way...I have restructured my database as by your suggestion. However now when my user logs in I require my application to Identify which user Is logged in. I have used Login and password method("provider:password"). Now Again I will need to retrace the phone number of the logged in user via UID. Please help me.

Comment: well then you need to have two indexes - one by phone one by UID. You should denormalize your data at your convenience.

Comment: Thank u . I have denormalised it as per your suggestion. and I was wondering if this is possible in firebase  

ref7= new Firebase("https://boiling-torch-4946.firebaseio.com/"+authData.getUid());

I got null pointer exception. thanks in advance

Comment: if it is a valid link I can't see why not.